# Use (on-premise) Gitlab server as OAuth provider

Tags: asp.net-core

I want to make a .NET Core 2.1 MVC app use my internal Gitlab server as OAuth authentication service provider. 
Inside Gitlab Admin Area I've added an Application:

```
Application Id: xxx
Secret: xxx
Callback url: http://localhost:5000/Account/ExternalLoginCallback
Trusted: Y
Scopes: - api (Access the authenticated user's API)
        - openid (Authenticate using OpenID Connect)
```

The `Startup.ConfigureServices` is similar to:

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddOAuth("GitLab", options => 
        {
            options.ClientId = "xxx";
            options.ClientSecret = "xxx";
            options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/Account/ExternalLoginCallback");

            options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://myGitlabServer/oauth/authorize";
            options.TokenEndpoint = "https://myGitlabServer/login/oauth/token";
            options.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://myGitlabServer/api/v4/user";

            options.SaveTokens = true;

            options.Events = new OAuthEvents
            {
                OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
                {
                    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, context.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
                    request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);

                    var response = await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    var user = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

                    context.RunClaimActions(user);
                }
            };
        });
```

On navigating to my apps' login page I can select GitLab as login provider and get redirected to the login page successfully. After singning in with the correct creds I would expect the controller to be called but the redirect fails.

```
Exception: OAuth token endpoint failure: Status: NotFound;Headers: Server: nginx
```

The corresponding request is:

```
GET http://localhost:5000/Account/ExternalLoginCallback?code=xxx&state=xxx HTTP/1.1
```

The `AccountController` signature looks like:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
    {
       ...
    }
```

Any ideas what I am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: There's a link-only deleted answer [pointing to this article](https://medium.com/@mauridb/using-oauth2-middleware-with-asp-net-core-2-0-b31ffef58cd0), maybe someone can write a complete answer with that.

Answer (score 0):

There where several things to be corrected.

First localhost does not apply to an application deployed somewhere in your network, so I had to change the Callback url from

```
http://localhost:5000/Account/ExternalLoginCallback
```

to

```
Callback url: http://{IP}:5000/signin-gitlab
```

Note the renaming of `/Account/ExternalLoginCallback` to just `/signin-gitlab`.

`Startup.ConfigureServices` (relevant parts) now:

```
        ...

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {

            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddOAuth("Gitlab", options =>
        {
            options.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;

            // App creds
            options.ClientId = "xxx";
            options.ClientSecret = "xxx";                

            options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-gitlab");

            options.AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://myGitlabServer/oauth/authorize";
            options.TokenEndpoint = "https://myGitlabServer/oauth/token";
            options.UserInformationEndpoint = "https://myGitlabServer/api/v4/user";

            options.SaveTokens = true;

            options.Events = new OAuthEvents
            {
                OnCreatingTicket = async context =>
                {
                    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, context.Options.UserInformationEndpoint);
                    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", context.AccessToken);
                    request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                    var response = await context.Backchannel.SendAsync(request, context.HttpContext.RequestAborted);
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    var user = JObject.Parse(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

                    // Add claims

                    var userId = user.Value<string>("username");
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userId))
                    {
                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userId, ClaimValueTypes.String, context.Options.ClaimsIssuer));
                        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userId);
                    }

                    var name = user.Value<string>("name");
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
                    {
                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, name, ClaimValueTypes.String, context.Options.ClaimsIssuer));
                        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.GivenName, name);
                    }

                    var email = user.Value<string>("email");
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
                    {
                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, email, ClaimValueTypes.Email, context.Options.ClaimsIssuer));
                        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Email, email);
                    }

                    var avatar = user.Value<string>("avatar_url");
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(avatar))
                    {
                        context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Uri, avatar, ClaimValueTypes.String, context.Options.ClaimsIssuer));
                        options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(ClaimTypes.Uri, avatar);
                    }
                }
            };
        })
        .AddCookie();

        ...
```

Inside my `AccountController` I have 2 methods to handle external logins:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult ExternalLogin(string provider, string returnUrl = null)
    {
        // Request a redirect to the external login provider.
        var redirectUrl = Url.Action(nameof(ExternalLoginCallback), "Account", new { returnUrl });
        var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(provider, redirectUrl);

        return Challenge(properties, provider);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
    {
        if (remoteError != null)
        {
            ErrorMessage = $"Error from external provider: {remoteError}";
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
        }

        var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();

        if (info == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
        }

        // Sign in 
        var result = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false, bypassTwoFactor: true);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByLoginAsync(info.LoginProvider, info.ProviderKey);
            var claimsPrincipal = await this._signInManager.CreateUserPrincipalAsync(user);
            var identity = claimsPrincipal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;

            await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(identity));

            var updateResult = await _signInManager.UpdateExternalAuthenticationTokensAsync(info);
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }

        if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Lockout));
        }
        else
        {
            // If the user doesn't have an account, then ask to create one
            ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
            ViewData["LoginProvider"] = info.LoginProvider;
            var email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
            return View("ExternalLogin", new ExternalLoginViewModel { Email = email });
        }
    }
```

Finally the view part inside my login view:

```
        <section>
            <h4>Use another service to log in.</h4>
            <hr />
            @{
                var loginProviders = (await SignInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
                if (loginProviders.Count == 0)
                {
                    <div>
                        <p>
                            There are no external authentication services configured. See <a href="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715">this article</a>
                            for details on setting up this ASP.NET application to support logging in via external services.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                }
                else
                {
                    <form asp-action="ExternalLogin" asp-route-returnurl="@Context.Request.Query["returnUrl"]" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
                        <div>
                            <p>
                                @foreach (var provider in loginProviders)
                                {
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-gitlab" name="provider" value="@provider.Name" title="Log in using your @provider.DisplayName account"><i class="fab fa-@provider.Name.ToLower()"></i>&nbsp; @provider.Name</button>
                                }
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                }
            }
        </section>
```